# How to remove unneeded dlls from Nuget package in Net7

Tags: c#, dll, nuget, .net-7.0

In NetFx you could simply remove unneeded dlls from a Nuget package by right clicking the dll and selecting remove as showin the following example where I removed the Avalon Dock dlls from Xceed:[image]

In Net7 you can't do this and have to edit the .csproj file instead. However in this example all that appears for Xceed is:

```
 <ItemGroup>
<PackageReference Include="Extended.Wpf.Toolkit" Version="4.4.0" />
```

I tried tinkering around with the MSBuild tags such as

```
<ItemGroup>
<PackageReference Include="Extended.Wpf.Toolkit" Version="4.4.0" />
```

<Compile="$(TargetDir)*.Wpf.Toolkit.NET5.dll" Exclude="$(TargetDir)*.Wpf.AvalonDock.*"/>

but the Avalon Dock dlls still get compiled and appears in the output folder:

[image]

How do I remove these unneeded package dlls in Net7 ?

Comment: Taking a step back... Why do you want to do this? Most assemblies are only actually loaded when a type in them is referenced

Comment: I also have the same concern, how are you sure that these are not actually needed?

Comment: There is an entry **"Remove Unused References"** in the project's context menu.

Comment: Look at [Trim self-contained deployments and executables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/trimming/trim-self-contained)

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. I want to remove AvalonDock beause it adds a lot of localization folders in addition to the unused dlls which clutter up my output folder. I didn't neeed them in NetFx so why should I not be able to do without them in Net7? Clicking on Remove unused references throws an MS Build exception "InvalidProjectFileException". As I use ClickOnce for deployment trimming wouldn't seem to be an option